# Cannot cast from View to EditTextPreference

Tags: android

I have defined the layout of my settings activity like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<PreferenceCategory 
    android:title="Second Category"
    android:key="second_category">

    <EditTextPreference
        android:id="@+id/pcnSetting"
        android:key="pcn"
        android:title="Set Canton Digits" 
        android:summary="Define your canton digits"
        android:dialogTitle="Set Canton Digits"
        android:dialogMessage="Please add your canton digits"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:maxLength="4"/>

</PreferenceCategory>
```

I want to import the `EditTextPreference` to my java code, just to be sure that the user typed in at least and maximum 4 digits.

This is how I try to get the `EditTextPreference` into java

```
    canton = (EditTextPreference)findViewById(R.id.pcnSetting);
```

But `Eclipse` gives me this error:

```
Cannot cast from View to EditTextPreference
```

Why does this happend? And how can I check if the user typed in at least and maximum `4` `int's`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EditTextPreference is not a View, it is a preference. So you have to use [findPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html#findPreference%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)() in your PreferenceActivity. You can then do EditTextPreference.getEdittext to get the view from this preference

Comment: How can I know if the user pressed the "Ok" button in this EdittextPreferences?

Comment: override it's method onDialogClosed (boolean positiveResult)

Comment: Use setOnPreferenceChangeListener to set a preference change listener, so that as soon as Ok is hit you will get callback

Answer (score 1):

Because EditTextPreference doesn't extend View, it extends DialogPreference

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html

Comment: String text = ((EditTextPreference)findPreference("pcn")).getText();